# Angular bootstrap dropdown auto-close not working when set to outside click

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

It is a simple dropdown which is supposed to close only on outside click.
It used to work in the earlier version (0.13).

Am I doing something wrong.
Don't want to have a work around like stop propagation and prevent default. That is my last resort.

Below is the plunkr for a simple dropdown:

http://plnkr.co/edit/A2vDHb43PThalcHAhLkJ?p=preview

```
    <span class="dropdown" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" uib-dropdown-toggle>
        Click me for a dropdown, yo!
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `uib-dropdown-menu` directive:

```
<ul uib-dropdown-menu class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ofl92a0Dk3l0seDriMgO?p=preview)